# Search custom field in Salesforce

Tags: custom-field

Search custom field in Salesforce without giving object name. I know the custom field name but I don't know in which object it's created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Setup**.  In the **Quick Find** box (in the left hand side), type your field name (of course, it shows blank), but now press Enter.  Doing this, will search for the field name.  It will show the field name, the related object as well

**Example.**

1. I'm searching for field called "Title". I typed Title in the quick find box in the Setup. It shows blank as seen below.

[image]

2. Now press Enter.  And then it shows the results.

[image]

Comment: Still it's not getting the result

Comment: Updated the answer with screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You can use workbench to get to know the object name on which the field has been created.
log in to workbench.developerforce.com
Here is the path info->metadata&components and choose CustomField in dropdown.